# How to Bind Checkbox to Recalculate Dynamic Data in Angular 6 using Type Script

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, rxjs

I wanted to manipulate the results of data when checkbox event is changed. I populate the dynamic data into a table and should be filtered when an option is not included.

Is it possible to use rxjs to filter the data?
What is the best way or method to achieve data binding?
Should I move some code to my service so that two component can share data?

[Here's the code!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fya5of)

Comment: do you want to show results based on checkbox? if english or spanish checked?

Comment: yes any of the option was unchecked, all data must change..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove [value] of your checkbox, only [(ngModel)]

```
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" 
        [attr.id]="filters.question + '_' + (i+1)" 
         [(ngModel)]="option.checked" />
```

Well, now your "option" can't be an string. Yes, your filters.rows is an array of string. We can transform in an array of Object

```
   //when you make the _newArray.push, you must make some like
   _newArray.push({
              question : item.DQuestionName,
              text: item.DQuestionText,
              rows : item.DOptions.map((p)=>{
                         return {text:p,checked:false}
                     }),
              columns: ["responses","%","Rank","low","high","+/-"]
            });
```

See how transform the array item.DOptions in an array of object using map

The label becomes like

```
<label [attr.for]="filters.question + '_' + (i+1)">{{option.text}}
</label>
```

Now if you write in your .html

```
        <pre> Lang:{{_filtersArray[0].rows|json}}</pre>
        <pre> X1:{{_filtersArray[1].rows|json}}</pre>
        <pre> X2:{{_filtersArray[2].rows|json}}</pre>
```

You can see the checked

With the code modiffied we can make a function getter like

```
get response()
  {
    return this._finalArray.map((p)=>{
      return {question:p.question,rows:p.rows.filter(r=>r.checked).map(q=>q.fields)}
    })
  }
```

That's, with each element of this._finalArray, we create an object. This object has two properties, "question" (equal the question) and rows. Rows is an array. first filter the response checked, then convert this response checked to get only the property "fields"

You can see the result as:

```
<pre> {{response|json}}</pre>
```

Comment: this is a start appreciate it, anyway for question component is there a way I can bind them to DValues too? so _dataArr will only show checked values. for example if English is unchecked "Respondent 1 and Respondent 3 in json file will not be included in _dataArr? I feel the need to refactor my code

Comment: @Yzak, I completed my answer to get the response (I'am in hurry and I have no time to get the %), but I hope this help you. (NOTE: Put {{row.text}} to see the text of the row).